# JS can't read a row generated by JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In an HTML file, I use JS to generate table rows to show data returned by database:

```
function appendResult(data) {
                var result = JSON.parse(data);
                var row = result.length;
                if (row == 0) {
                    $("#productList").html("No matching result.");
                } else {
                    $("#productList").html("");
                    var i = 0;
                    while (i < row) {
                        // For each return record, create a new row, then write data into cell accordingly. New records are always written to last cell.
                        $("#productList").append("<tr class='hightLight'><td class='sku'></td><td class='productName'></td><td class='description'></td><td class='qtyPerCtn'></td><td class='weight'></td><td class='upc'></td><td class='gtin'></td><td class='vendorCode'></td><td class='note'></td></tr>");
                        $("td.sku").last().html(result[i]["sku"]);
                        $("td.productName").last().html(result[i]["productName"]);
                        $("td.description").last().html(result[i]["description"]);
                        $("td.qtyPerCtn").last().html(result[i]["qtyPerCtn"]);
                        $("td.weight").last().html(result[i]["masterWeightLb"]);
                        $("td.upc").last().html(result[i]["UPC"]);
                        $("td.gtin").last().html(result[i]["gtin"]);
                        $("td.vendorCode").last().html(result[i]["vendorCode"]);
                        $("td.note").last().html(result[i]["note"]);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Then I have a function to highlight the row when the mouse rolls over it:

```
// high light row when mouse roll over
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hightLight").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("highLightOnRollOver");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("highLightOnRollOver");
    });
});
```

But apparently this doesn't work. The highlight function doesn't work. But if I put a row in plain html, it works:

```
<table>
<tr class="hightLight"><td>test</td></tr>
</table>
```

Does it mean JS functions can't identify the elements generated by JS? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work even if you add elements after the dom is ready:

```
// high light row when mouse roll over
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table")
        .on('mouseenter', ".hightLight", function () {
            $(this).addClass("highLightOnRollOver");
        })
        .on('mouseleave', ".hightLight", function () {
            $(this).removeClass("highLightOnRollOver");
        });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use delegation, like this:

```
    $(document).on("hover", ".hightLight", function () {
```

If the javascript is sourced before the DOM is created, it wont see it. Delegation gets around it by saying "look for a hover within `document`, if that hover is within `.hightLight`, then do this...

You could replace also `document` with a closer parent of `.hightLight`... it looks like `#productList` would probably work well.